# Python Pandas:Need help making a chart with 2 line plots from a single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

so I have automobile fuel economy data and I just want to chart the average overall mpg of Honda vs Toyota. I can do this by making a dataframe containing just Honda data and then creating a dataframe containing just Toyota data. Then plot the 2 data sets. But I was wondering if I can make the same chart from a single dataframe consisting of both Honda and Toyota data. Here's my ipython notebook ( http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/pybokeh/f0f93adb18f47162a866 )

I was thinking pandas api has built-in features that allows you to group data within a single dataframe and chart the groupings on-the-fly, maybe using the by='make' option, but that didn't work.
Any help or suggestions is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Reorient your DataFrame so that Honda and Toyota are separate columns rather than a level of the index.

Comment: I want to be able to do this without having to do extensive data manipulation. Basically, after doing the groupby and then the mean aggregate function, I want to be able to just plot the resulting data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that when you created 'honda_toyota_average' it became a Series object in which the 'make' column cannot be accessed. Presumably the plot function is therefore also unable to make use of it.

If instead you use the pivot_table method on the dataframe you can easily create a honda and a toyota column and calculate the average overall mpg at the same time. Then the plot of the dataframe will get you the right graph:

```
honda_toyota_vehicle_non_hybrid = vehicles[criteria1 & criteria2 & criteria3 & criteria4]


honda_toyota_average = honda_toyota_vehicle_non_hybrid.pivot_table('comb08', index='year', columns='make', aggfunc='mean')

honda_toyota_average.plot()
<matplotlib.axes.AxesSubplot at 0x11042c2d0>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.  It just shows there are so many different ways to group the data and make calculations, but I needed the "one" way in order to accomplish what I wanted.

Comment: You're welcome. I'd just seen it in McKinney's Python for Data Analysis yesterday.